# How does using CSS 3D Transforms affect SEO?

Tags: css, 3d, seo, transform, googlebot

Google's made a big deal of "if you hide it, it won't count." However, google cache shows it doesn't understand a lot of things correctly. Maybe google sees something as hidden when it should show or shows when it should be hidden.

So, I ask about CSS 3D transforms.
Take this example for example: 
[3d Carousel CSS](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/carousel-02-dynamic.html)
Ignoring Javascript, if it were instead coded to to run on pure CSS and rotate on it's own (kind of a replacement for a bannder display)... what would be the SEO effect? Would it treat items that start facing away from the user as hidden and what's facing the user as SEO-able content? Would it ignore 3D and treat them as just divs to look at? Or would it ignore 3d as if it were ALL hidden?
Seems important to know for design purposes if one intends to use 3d effects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions belong on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check what Google's robots see, you should not rely on cache, but on the 'Fetch as Google' feature from Google Webmaster Tools. Cache lags behind the index (sometimes a lot).

Your 'if you hide it, it won't count' rule is not correct. It's: 'if it is never displayed to users, it won't count'. In other words, if users need to click on a button or on a tab menu to display content, it will count for relevancy and ranking (i.e. SEO), but Google will discount such content somehow. Ditto for CSS effects hiding or displaying content.

Google can execute Javascript and take CSS effects into account in general, but always check with the 'Fetch as Google' feature to be sure.